# RootReduce-Part of Solve

Tags: equation-solving, functions, polynomials

I have given the following expression in $M$ and $z$:
\begin{equation}
    a = \frac{-4 M^2+M (-3 z-5)+\frac{1.1875 z}{\sqrt{\frac{0.015625 z}{M+1}-1.5625} \sqrt{\frac{0.765625 z}{M+1}-0.5625}}-1}{M+0.75 z+1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
In `Mathematica`, this is

```
a = (-1. - 4. M^2 + M (-5. - 3. z) + (1.1875 z) / (Sqrt[-1.5625 + (0.015625 z)/(1 + M)] Sqrt[-0.5625 + (0.765625 z)/(1 + M)]))/(1. + 1. M + 0.75 z)
```

If I set this expression to $0$ and solve for $M$, I get the 5 roots as

```
Solve[a == 0, M]
(* {{M -> Root[900.0 - 1909.0 z + \(9900.0 - 13690.0 z + 98.0 z^2) #1 
     + \(38700.0 - 30597.0 z - 14514.0 z^2 + 147.0 z^3) #1^2 
     + \(65700.0 - 27760.0 z - 14612.0 z^2) #1^3 
     + \(50400.0 - 8944.0 z) #1^4 
     + 14400.0 #1^5 &, 1]},
     <<4>>} *)
```

(To clean the output, I truncated all trailing zeros but the first.)

Is there a way to transform expression $a$ to the polynomial given in `Root[]`? Maybe with `RootReduce`?

I only managed to get the expression to the following form by manual manipulation:

```
b = Expand[Together[a]*Denominator[Together[a]]];
c = b[[1]]^2 == (-b[[2;;Length[b]]])^2 // (Head[#][Subtract@@#,0] &);
d = Collect[Together[c[[1]]]*Denominator[Together[c[[1]]]], M]
(* -14.0625 M^6 - 0.107666 M^5 (587.755 + 16.8345 z)
   -0.107666 M^4 (1053.06 + 9.94104 z - 193.379 z^2)
   -0.107666 M^3 (946.939 - 82.3764 z - 453.025 z^2 - 98.068 z^3) 
   -0.107666 M^2 (440.816 - 138.431 z - 338.9 z^2 - 97.4014 z^3 + 1. z^4)
   -0.107666 M (97.9592 - 74.1406 z - 92.2404 z^2 + 0.666667 z^3)
   -0.107666 (8.16327 - 11.1927 z - 12.9864 z^2) *)
```

I induced an additional root

```
Solve[Denominator[a] == 0, M]
(* {{M -> -1. - 0.75 z}} *)
```

which shows in

```
Solve[d == 0, M]
```

So without this additional root,

```
e = Chop[Collect[PolynomialQuotient[d, M - Solve[Denominator[a] == 0, M][[1,1,2]], M], M]]
(* -14.0625 M^5 + M^4 (-49.2188 + 8.73437 z) 
   + M^3 (-64.1602 + 27.1094 z + 14.2695 z^2) 
   + M^2 (-37.793 + 29.8799 z + 14.1738 z^2 - 0.143555 z^3) 
   + M (-9.66797 + 13.3691 z - 0.0957031 z^2) 
   -0.878906 + 1.86426 z *)
```

this is, modulo renormalization by $14400/14.0625$, the root witch Mathematica found by `Solve[a == 0, M]`.

How does `Solve` bring expression $a$ in canonical polynomial form, on which it applies `Root`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the polynomial, the easiest way is

```
res = M /. Rationalize@Solve[a == 0, M];

poly = res[[1, 1]][M]
```

> ```
> 900 + 14400 M^5 + M^4 (50400 - 8944 z) - 1909 z + 
>  M^3 (65700 - 27760 z - 14612 z^2) + M (9900 - 13690 z + 98 z^2) + 
>  M^2 (38700 - 30597 z - 14514 z^2 + 147 z^3)
> ```

Now I don't know what `Solve` does, but I did the following.

> Take the numerator
>
> Isolate the term with the square root
>
> Square both sides
>
> Take the numerator of the subtracted terms
>
> Factor, take the quintic, and collect in terms of $M$

```
Collect[
 FactorList[
   Numerator[
    Together[
     Numerator[
       Rationalize[a]] //. {e1_ + e2_ Power[e3_, r_Rational] :> 
        With[{d = Denominator[r]}, -(-e1)^d + (e2 e3^r)^d]}]]][[-1, 1]], M]
```

> ```
> 900 + 14400 M^5 + M^4 (50400 - 8944 z) - 1909 z + 
>  M^3 (65700 - 27760 z - 14612 z^2) + M (9900 - 13690 z + 98 z^2) + 
>  M^2 (38700 - 30597 z - 14514 z^2 + 147 z^3)
> ```

p.s.

There is no hope in solving this quintic in terms of radicals. For instance, when $z = 1$ the Galois group is $S_5$. You can see this using `Galois.nb` found [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/158/)

```
GaloisGroup[poly /. z -> 1]
```

> ```
> {SymmetricGroup[5]}
> ```

Comment: Thank you, your solutions with `ReplaceRepeated` and `RuleDelayed` is much more sophisticated then my humble attempt. I was hoping to circumvent using `Solve` and get the Root-Expression directly. But this 'half-manual' approach seems to be how one has to proceed. At least it is almost 30 times as fast as Rationalize@Solve. 
And thanks for the link, there I found some helpful resources.